# Evaluate already parsed duration expression

Tags: parsing, go, abstract-syntax-tree, evaluation

I'm writing a tool which reads go code and parses some duration expressions like: `dur := 5 * time.Minute`. I already have the parsing step done and got a `*ast.BinaryExpr`. How can I evaluate this expression and get its value?

Is there something in the toolchain/packages or do I need to go by hand?

Answer (score 0):

I think `parser` package is the one your looking for.
go also has a package named eval (`https://godoc.org/github.com/apaxa-go/eval`) that evaluates expressions.
And there are two libraries that might help you down the line.

`https://github.com/PaesslerAG/gval`

`https://github.com/Knetic/govaluate`

> Gval (Go eVALuate) provides support for evaluating arbitrary expressions, in particular Go-like expressions.

Good luck!